# How to Check if Column is NULL Instead of Empty Using PHP and MSSQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have PHP Code that is supposed to display the image name that is saved into my MSSQL table's row column `photo`. Some rows have the `photo` column set to NULL while some have the data `02.jpg` in the `photo` column. If i use the code below, `02.jpg` does not show up because it starts with zero. I am looking to find a way to check if the column is set to NULL rather than empty, because empty is not allowing some image names.

Here is the PHP code:

```
$picature2 = "SELECT photo1 FROM used_trailers1 WHERE orderid = $sn";
$query1=mssql_query($picature2, $conn);
$array1=mssql_fetch_assoc($query1);
$picature2=stripslashes($array1['photo1']);

if (empty($picature2['photo1'])){
    $picature2= "No Image";
} else {
    $picature2=stripslashes($array1['photo1']);
}
```

The code above correctly displays the "No Image" if the `photo` column is set to NULL, but if the `photo` column is `02lady.jpg` then it will not work because it starts with a zero.

Here is what I tried:

```
if (IS_NULL($picature2['photo1'])){
```

So far that does not work and does not display the "No Image" if the column data for `photo` is NULL.

Thanks for any help. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `$picature2['photo1']===null`

Comment: try 'is_null' or 'isset' : http://in3.php.net/is_null

Comment: It starts with `0` so what? `'02.jpg'` won't be treated as empty.

Comment: You're checking `$picature2` then using `$array1`. Does your code work even somehow?

Comment: It does get treated as empty. I am using an older version of MSSQL so maybe that is why. Yes, my code does work, some how.

Comment: What does `var_dump($picature2['photo1'])` produce?

Comment: It appears to be producing `NULL` even if the `photo1` column data is `lady.jpg`.

Comment: Does querying the database with hard coded values produce the same result?

Comment: No, it displays `83857914-avatar.jpg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

```
  if ($picature2['photo1']===null || ctype_space($picature2['photo1'])){
    $picature2= "No Image";
    }

     else {
        $picature2=stripslashes($array1['photo1']);
    }
```

Comment: I tried using this, but it still does not return the "No Image" value. I have a delete button to reset the `photo` column to NULL and the sql for that is this : `$sql = "UPDATE used_trailers1 SET photo1 = NULL WHERE orderid = '$sn'";
 $retval2 = mssql_query($sql, $dbLink);` is my $sql not setting the column to NULL?

Comment: What's the output `echo gettype($picature2['photo1'])` of?

Comment: The output is `string`.

Comment: So its not `NULL`. Try to `trim` it and check its type again.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `trim`?

Comment: if its a string and you `trim` it it will still be a string.

Comment: Check if `echo strlen(trim($picature2['photo1']));` is `0` or you can check with `ctype_space` function http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-space.php

Comment: I got `string(19) "83857914-avatar.jpg"` when I used the code `$trimmed = trim($picature2);
var_dump($trimmed);
`

Comment: When I delete the image from the `photo1` column it appears as `string(0) ""`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php is_null() function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php

Answer (score 0):

You have the following

```
$picature2=stripslashes($array1['photo1']);
if (empty($picature2['photo1'])){
```

which assigns `photo1` to `$picature2` then you check `$picature2['photo1']` which `$picature2` isn't a array.

You should use the following

```
#$picature2=stripslashes($array1['photo1']);
#remove this because if you have NULL and use stripslashes it turns into ""
if($array1['photo1'] === NULL){
    $picature2 = "No Image";
}else{
    $picature2 = stripslashes($array1['photo1']);
}
```

Comment: Why to spread the logic across layers? You can even generate the result `html` in the query, but it makes no sense.